# Dask progress during task

Tags: python, pandas, dask, tqdm, dask-dataframe

With dask dataframe using
`df = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(df, npartitions=5)
series = df.apply(func) 
future = client.compute(series)
progress(future)`

In a jupyter notebook I can see progress bar for how many apply() calls completed per partition (e.g  2/5).
Is there a way for dask to report progress inside each partition?
Something like `tqdm` `progress_apply()` for pandas.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, how complete each call of `func()` is, then no, there is no way for Dask to know that. Dask calls python functions which run in their own python thread (python threads cannot be interrupted by another thread), and Dask only knows whether the call is done or not.

You could perhaps conceive of calling a function which has some internal callbacks or other reporting system, but I don't think I've seen anything like that.

Comment: Why not? Dask call `func` per dataframe row, so Dask knows when `func` is completed for each row (like tqdm). I would like to register a "hook" to that somehow..

Comment: Dask does *not* call func for each row, it calls pandas' `apply`

Comment: And is there a way to swap apply for tqdm progress apply?
Or alternatively, manually reporting progress to dask

Comment: Yes, you could write your own wrapper for apply which notifies the client somehow, but this is uncharted territory and you are on your own. The former may be possible if you use threads only, but I doubt that the output will be reasonable.